# React Native mobile app text not updating after lock screen

Tags: android, react-native

I have a mobile app developed in React Native.

1. I have a feature where the app can make calls using Twilio and there is a call screen that displays the normal information such as the caller id, duration of call, etc.
2. While the app is open everything works as expected but when the phone is in lock screen and the user receives a call 2 things happen

   1. The function that is used to display the call duration only display `00:00` but when I `console.log` the function the timer is running and the timer is logging the correct time
   2. After picking up the call the phone continues to ring even though the call has been answered
3. This only seems to happen on android devices and not iOS devices

I am assuming that this is an issue with the app being in the background and not active.

If more information is needed I can probably post some snippets but I cannot post specific code.